# can not output flash data when use redirect()->with() in laravel 5.2.45

Tags: laravel, redirect

Guys
I am using `laravel5.2.45`. when I use `redirect()->with()` to have a flash data within `routes.php`, I can not output cache data. here is my codes.

In `App/Http/routes.php`

```
    Route::get('hello', function(){
        return redirect('/')->with('ok',"success");
    });
```

In `index.blade.php`

```
    <div class="container">
      @if(session()->has('ok'))
         <?php echo session('ok'); ?>  // always null
      @endif
    </div>
```

No mattter what I do ,it can not print the session data. I also tried to use `Session::get('ok')', but it was still null.

I have updated my application by `composer update` and `compose dump-autoload`, but it still not work.

Anyone can helps?

Comment: Did you apply `web` middleware to the routes?

Comment: What is the driver for session ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I suggest you do.. start by creating couple of routes for testing..

```
Route::get('/test', function() { 
    return redirect('/test2')->with('ok', 'Working'); 
}

Route::get('/test2', function() { 
    return session('ok');
}
```

If this works then your session is working fine. If not, check to make sure you have one web middleware (not zero and not two). You can do that with `php artisan route:list`

Another possibility is that it's caused from having multiple redirects, I've see this a lot. And if this is the case, simply **reflash** after the first redirect.

You can find more info in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data

Comment: Thank you , I have sovle this problem. the reason for not working is because I used `web` middleware.  Now it work good after I remove the `web` middleware